# Nested recursive function is throwing an error

Tags: php, recursion, nested-function

I have a nested recursive function it's a task from codewars.

> persistence(39) === 3; // because 3 * 9 = 27, 2 * 7 = 14, 1 * 4 = 4
> and 4 has only one digit persistence(999) === 4; // because 9 * 9 * 9
> = 729, 7 * 2 * 9 = 126, 1 * 2 * 6 = 12, and finally 1 * 2 = 2;
> persistence(4) === 0; // because 4 is already a one-digit number

which throws :

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare rec();

```
function persistence(int $num): int {
    $str = (string)$num;
    $nums = str_split($str);
    $count = count($nums);

    if( $count === 0 ){
        return 0;
    }
    $x = 0;

    function rec($nums, $n) {

        $result = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($nums); ++$i) {
            if ($i == 0) {
                $result = $nums[$i];
            } else {
                $result *= $nums[$i];
            }
        }

        $num = implode('',$nums);
        $diff = $num - $result;
        if ( $diff != 0 ) {
            $n += 1;
            $result = str_split($result,1);
            return rec($result, $n);
        }
        return $n;
    }

    $result = rec($nums,$x);



    return (int)$result;

}
```

I've  tried to use an variable function

```
$rec = 'rec'; 
$result = $rec($nums,$n)
```

but there are another error :  `

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare rec()

`
PHP 7.4 version. Can anyone explain me what the problem is ?

Comment: Show the calling code that you need to use, some test data and expected result. At least then I can try and get it to run. i.e. An example I can just run and play with. :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't define the function inside the other function:

You have:

```php
function persistence(int $num): int {
    // code ...
    function rec($nums, $n) {
        // code ...
    }
}
```

This means that the function `rec` should be created each time the function `persistence` gets called.

You should define them first:

```php
function persistence(int $num): int {
    // code ...
}
function rec($nums, $n) {
    // code ...
}
```

And then call them to your liking, for example like you already do:

```php
$rec = 'rec'; 
$result = $rec($nums,$n)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I am trying to solve the code wars kata. So this is a necessary decision. Are there other ways?

Comment: Other ways for what exactly? Redefining the same function over and over will not help you in any way. If you are talking about recursion: This is about making **the calls** to the function recursive, not its definition/declaration.